# How to have default layers in OpenLayers not visible until selected?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I am new to OpenLayers and doing a project using OpenStreetMap. When I open the project the layers I currently have are already visible and on top of each other.

I would like to have my layers not displayed on the map until their check boxes are selected (have them unselected by default) but I cant seem to figure out how this is done.

I can provide code if it helps.

Comment: Yes, please post the code you currently have and explain the specific problem you're having.

Comment: Why are you using the [tag:leaflet] tag on this question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you think in layerswitcher control that not exists in OL3 but it was very usefull in OL2.

You could use Matt Walker's control in OL3. Follow the steps:

1. Download from https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher
2. Put it in the same folder of your aplication
3. All layers have to be Title property, and They have to be inside groups using ol.layer.Group. You could create diferent groups and set property visible = true in default layer (false to others).

Example:

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol3-layerswitcher-master/src/ol3-layerswitcher.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="ol3-layerswitcher-master/src/ol3-layerswitcher.js"></script>

<style>
   #map{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
  } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> ol3-layerswitcher</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: 
                [new ol.layer.Group({
                    'title': 'Base maps',
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            title: 'Water color',
                            type: 'base',
                            visible: false,
                            source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                layer: 'watercolor'
                            })
                        }),
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            title: 'OSM',
                            type: 'base',
                            visible: false,
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        }),
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            title: 'Satellite',
                            type: 'base',
                            visible: true,
                            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
                        })
                    ]
                }),
                new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Overlays',
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            title: 'Countries',
                            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                                url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
                                params: {'LAYERS': 'ne:ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines_shp'},
                                serverType: 'geoserver'
                            })
                        })
                    ]
                })
                ],  
                target: 'map',
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: ol.proj.transform([2.1, 41.50], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    zoom: 8
          })
        });

        var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
            tipLabel: 'Leyenda'
        });
        map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
        layerSwitcher.showPanel();
  </script></body></html>
```

Another online example: http://rawgit.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher/master/examples/layerswitcher.html

Hope this helps you !